# might we not say?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What might be the reason the author adds "might we not say" in his diatribe against boardinghouse life? Here's the context:

> "There is no chance for the development of the unhappy wife into a
>   mature and noble woman—the
>
> 'Perfect being, nobly planned,
>   To warn, to comfort, to command,'
>
> of the poet. Listlessness; emptiness; sloth; nerves; dyspepsia;
>   flirtations; prodigality; vain show; perhaps—often, might we not
>   say?—immorality, nay, infamy. These are the accomplishments which the
>   boarding-house life most tends to develop."
>
> [*whitmanarchive.org*](http://www.whitmanarchive.org/published/periodical/journalism/tei/per.00270.html)

I wonder if this remark indicates the author's intention to prevent his criticism from going too far.

Comment: It's a hedge. He doesn't want to be perceived as arrogating, but still wants to get his points across.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have mentioned this is **Walt Whitman** who is being quoted. Then, you should provided a link (based on a search at Google Books; do you have access to it?):

> [Newlyweds on Tour: Honeymooning in Nineteenth-century America](https://books.google.com/books?id=OEyrSF-SmdwC&pg=PA196&dq=%22Listlessness%3B%20emptiness%3B%20sloth%3B%20nerves%3B%20dyspepsia%3B%20flirtations%3B%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bmEyVZa2E83jsASMoIDoBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Listlessness%3B%20emptiness%3B%20sloth%3B%20nerves%3B%20dyspepsia%3B%20flirtations%3B%20%22&f=false) Barbara
>   Penner - 2009
>
> Echoing her three years later, **Walt Whitman** decried boardinghouses
>   as "fertile hot-bed[s] for evils" and reported that wives living in
>   them suffered from "listlessness; emptiness; sloth; nerves; dyspepsia;
>   flirtations; prodigality; vain show; perhaps—often, might we not say?—immorality, nay, infamy."

often, **might we not** say?

=

often, **wouldn't/isn't it possible to** describe it this way?

=

often, **am I wrong**?

It's like **asking for an approval/nodding** from an imaginary conversation partner/audience.

This is a **rhetoric question** addressed to the reader, with which Whitman wants to **soften**  his vituperative attacks against boarding houses and some of the women living in them.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to post the link for the quote.  The quote is included in: http://www.whitmanarchive.org/published/periodical/journalism/tei/per.00270.html